# How to resize an image set as an icon in java netbeans IDE 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans

I am very new to Java, I have learned how to add images in a `jLabel` as an icon in `netbeans`, but the image acts in a notorious way that is it becomes too big in a way that only part of it can be seen.

I have tried various ways but I didn't solve it, and most of the answers explain it by coding, a way which I am not familiar with.

So I am humbly asking for help on how i can make that image to fit on a small jLabel or if there is any other way to accomplish this. (The images are for a computer voting system that has has an image a check box and name.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can resize the image in the IDE...

[image]

or in SourceCode:

```
BufferedImage img;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedImage dimg = img.getScaledInstance(64, 64,        Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(dimg);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me. and as an addition from my the experience  i have got right now, if you do not see a "Resize" button from the menu that appears after right clicking, the text "Open in external window" might have appeared, you can click that and then an external window will appear like that for paint program in window, there you can do lot more stuff rather than just resizing the image.